# How do i remove a specefic character from a file?

Tags: java, regex, replace, character

I have this JSON file in this format;

```
[{
"item-id" : "0",
"item-name" : "Dwarf remains",
"item-examine" : "The body of a Dwarf savaged by Goblins.",
"shop-value" : "0.0",
"low-alch" : "0.0",
"high-alch" : "0.0",
"stab-bonus" : "0",
"slash-bonus" : "0",
"crush-bonus" : "0",
"magic-bonus" : "0",
"ranged-bonus" : "0",
"stab-defence" : "0",
"slash-defence" : "0",
"crush-defence" : "0",
"magic-defence" : "0",
"ranged-defence" : "0",
"strength-bonus" : "0",
"prayer-bonus" : "0",
},
{
"item-id" : "1",
"item-name" : "Toolkit",
"item-examine" : "Good for repairing a broken cannon.",
"shop-value" : "0.0",
"low-alch" : "0.0",
"high-alch" : "0.0",
"stab-bonus" : "0",
"slash-bonus" : "0",
"crush-bonus" : "0",
"magic-bonus" : "0",
"ranged-bonus" : "0",
"stab-defence" : "0",
"slash-defence" : "0",
"crush-defence" : "0",
"magic-defence" : "0",
"ranged-defence" : "0",
"strength-bonus" : "0",
"prayer-bonus" : "0",
}]
```

But with 25 000 entries

But in the file there is something wrong;

```
"prayer-bonus" : "0",
```

should be

```
"prayer-bonus" : "0"
```

How can i use regex or whatever to only replace the last bit?

Im using java.

By the way: the value is not always "0"

So how can i have it be a wildcard so it replaces all ?

Comment: [You can do via command line](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/unix-sed-tutorial-replace-text-inside-a-file-using-substitute-command/).

Comment: Why don't you simply use String.replace()? You don't need any regex to replace `"prayer-bonus" : "0",` by `"prayer-bonus" : "0"`

Comment: @JBNizet i'm sure it may not always be "0". By this logic, he could just hard code this exact file into his program.

Comment: open notepad++ and replace the string

Comment: Use String.contains() - search for prayer-bonus, then get last character on line and if its a , drop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this (written in java style, to use with `replaceAll()` method):

```
search: (?<!\\\\)(\"(?>[^\\\"]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\.)*+\"),(\\s*+})
replace: $1$2
```

The main interest of this pattern is that you avoid escaped double quotes that may be inside quotes.

Example:

```
String pattern = "(?<!\\\\)(\"(?>[^\\\"]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\.)*+\"),(\\s*+})";
String result = yourJson.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$2");
```

Comment: worked like a charm thank you very much this website is great!

Answer (score 0):

use sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\("prayer-bonus" : "0"\),/\1/' file
```

To match any number:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\("prayer-bonus" : "[0-9]*"\),/\1/' file
```

Comment: This is helpfull thanks! Sed is built into windows? and the value"0" can be anything not only 0 any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be trying to patch a problem caused by improperly formed JSON blobs. You could take the other responder's answer of using sed to fix these symptoms but the problem lies in how the JSON is being created.

Answer (score 0):

Any text editor will do the trick.

[image]

Or you can call string replace from java. No need for regex.

Comment: Its not always "0" thats my problem :)