# Unexpected character (A) at position JSON

Tags: java, json

I have no idea what the problem is;

```
[13-11-13 19:28]: Unexpected character (A) at position 32480.
[13-11-13 19:28]: Succesfully loaded 0 item definitions!
[13-11-13 19:28]:   at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
[13-11-13 19:28]:   at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
[13-11-13 19:28]:   at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
[13-11-13 19:28]:   at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
[13-11-13 19:28]:   at server.world.ItemHandler.initItemDefs(ItemHandler.java:375)
[13-11-13 19:28]:   at server.world.ItemHandler.<init>(ItemHandler.java:37)
[13-11-13 19:28]:   at server.GameServer.<clinit>(GameServer.java:68)
[13-11-13 19:28]:   at server.Engine.main(Engine.java:18)
```

It redirects to this line:

```
JSONArray input = (JSONArray) JSONReader.PARSER.parse(new FileReader(FileName));
```

in this method:

```
public void initItemDefs(String FileName) {
    int itemAmount = 0;
    try {
        JSONArray input = (JSONArray) JSONReader.PARSER.parse(new FileReader(FileName));
        for (Object o : input) {
            JSONObject config = (JSONObject) o;
            try {
                if (config.get("item-id") != null) {
                    int itemId =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("item-id").toString());
                    String itemName = config.get("item-name").toString();
                    String itemExamine = config.get("item-examine").toString();
                    double shopvalue =  Double.parseDouble(config.get("shop-value").toString());
                    double lowalch =  Double.parseDouble(config.get("low-alch").toString());
                    double highalch =  Double.parseDouble(config.get("high-alch").toString());
                    int stabBonus =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("stab-bonus").toString());
                    int slashBonus =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("slash-bonus").toString());
                    int crushBonus =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("crush-bonus").toString());
                    int magicBonus =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("magic-bonus").toString());
                    int rangedBonus =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("ranged-bonus").toString());
                    int stabDefence =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("stab-defence").toString());
                    int slashDefence =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("slash-defence").toString());
                    int crushDefence =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("crush-defence").toString());
                    int magicDefence =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("magic-defence").toString());
                    int rangedDefence =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("ranged-defence").toString());
                    int strengthBonus =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("strength-bonus").toString());
                    int prayerBonus =  Integer.parseInt(config.get("prayer-bonus").toString());

                    newItemList(itemId, itemName, itemExamine, shopvalue, lowalch, highalch, new int [] {stabBonus, slashBonus, crushBonus, magicBonus, rangedBonus, stabDefence, slashDefence, crushDefence, magicDefence, rangedDefence, strengthBonus, prayerBonus});
                    itemAmount++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Succesfully loaded " +itemAmount+ " item definitions!");
}
```

The file format is like this:

```
[{
"item-id" : "0",
"item-name" : "Dwarf remains",
"item-examine" : "The body of a Dwarf savaged by Goblins.",
"shop-value" : "0.0",
"low-alch" : "0.0",
"high-alch" : "0.0",
"stab-bonus" : "0",
"slash-bonus" : "0",
"crush-bonus" : "0",
"magic-bonus" : "0",
"ranged-bonus" : "0",
"stab-defence" : "0",
"slash-defence" : "0",
"crush-defence" : "0",
"magic-defence" : "0",
"ranged-defence" : "0",
"strength-bonus" : "0",
"prayer-bonus" : "0",
},
{
"item-id" : "1",
"item-name" : "Toolkit",
"item-examine" : "Good for repairing a broken cannon.",
"shop-value" : "0.0",
"low-alch" : "0.0",
"high-alch" : "0.0",
"stab-bonus" : "0",
"slash-bonus" : "0",
"crush-bonus" : "0",
"magic-bonus" : "0",
"ranged-bonus" : "0",
"stab-defence" : "0",
"slash-defence" : "0",
"crush-defence" : "0",
"magic-defence" : "0",
"ranged-defence" : "0",
"strength-bonus" : "0",
"prayer-bonus" : "0",
}]
```

But then 25k entries.

Comment: Your JSON seems to be malformed.

Comment: Paste the contents of the file, it's not valid JSON.

Comment: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ tends to help

Comment: A common cause of this error is unescaped quotation marks in the value of a json element.

Comment: Can you paste your JSON object as well?

Comment: I presume [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959300/how-do-i-remove-a-specefic-character-from-a-file) is the format you are using.

Comment: Alright ill post the format

Comment: @user2988643 high-alch, low-alch and shop values aren't negative, since RSGP is in integer form only. Just a heads-up ;)

Comment: Somewhere in there is a "A" outside of quotes.  Since upper-case characters are rare, you can probably find it with a text editor search, after setting the search options to respect case.

Comment: I've faced such a problem and I solved it by replacing `new FileReader(FileName)` with `new File(FileName)`.